# Anyone have a URL Shortening T-Sql code?

Tags: t-sql, url-shortener

I'm wanting to shorten some url's and sql guids into some 'short' url format.

Does anyone have any code or links to some code, for url shortening in T-Sql?

Answer (score 4):

I got my answer :)

/me tips his hat to google, yet again.

#### Definitions

1. Base36 == a-z 0-9

this means, i want a shortened url. so i insert it into a db to grab a unique identity number. I then convert this int/big int to a base36 string.

Links I based my code off.

1. [Converting ints to base36](http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/05/converting-decimal-to-hexadecimal-with.html).
2. [Converting base36 to ints](http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/05/converting-hexadecimal-or-binary-to.html).

...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertIntegerToBase36] 
(
    @IntegerValue INTEGER
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(100) = '',
        @ShortCharacterSet VARCHAR(36) = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    
    WHILE @IntegerValue > 0 BEGIN
        SET @Result = SUBSTRING(@ShortCharacterSet, @IntegerValue % LEN(@ShortCharacterSet) + 1, 1) + @Result;
        SET @IntegerValue = @IntegerValue / LEN(@ShortCharacterSet);
    END
    
    RETURN @Result
END
```

...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertBase36ToInteger]
(
    @EncodedValue VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Decoding encoded-strings to ints: http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.com/2009/05/converting-hexadecimal-or-binary-to.html
    
    DECLARE @Result INTEGER = 0,
        @Index INTEGER = 0,
        @ShortCharacterSet VARCHAR(36) = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
        
    WHILE @Index < LEN(@EncodedValue)  
         SELECT @Result = @Result + POWER(LEN(@ShortCharacterSet), @Index) *   
                          (CHARINDEX  
                             (SUBSTRING(@EncodedValue, LEN(@EncodedValue) - @Index, 1)  
                             , @ShortCharacterSet) - 1  
                          ),  
                @Index = @Index + 1;  
 
    
    RETURN @Result
END
```

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Since string manipulation is something T-SQL doesn't do so well, this is something I'd use a CLR stored procedure for. Then you can use any .Net shortening function.